# Perron Solution is Precisely Poisson Integral on Punctured Disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework question that asks

> Define $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z| < 1 \}$, and let $h(\zeta)$ be a continuous function on $\partial D$.  Show that the Perron solution $\tilde{h}(z)$ is the Poisson integral of the restriction of $h(\zeta)$ to the unit circle $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}$, no matter how the value of $h(0)$ is chosen.

Here is my attempt.  First I look at the Perron family of subsolutions
$$ \mathcal{F}_h = \{ u \in \mathcal{SH}(D) : \limsup_{z \to \zeta} u(z) \leq h(\zeta) \}, $$
where $\mathcal{SH}(D)$ denotes the set of subharmonic functions on $D$.  Then the Perron solution is defined to be $\tilde{h}(z) = \sup_{u \in \mathcal{F}_h} u(z)$.  Let $h_p$ denote the Poisson integral of the restriction of $h(\zeta)$ to the unit circle.  Set $\tilde{h}_p = h_p \mid_{D}$.  Then $\tilde{h}_p \in \mathcal{F}_h$, so $\tilde{h}_p \leq \tilde{h}$.  Next, $\tilde{h} \leq \tilde{h}_p$ by using the maximum principle.

I'm almost certain this is wrong, but didn't want to write nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Perron family $\mathcal{F}_h$ takes the value $h(0)$ into account, so $\tilde{h}_p \in \mathcal{F}_h$ only if $h_p(0) \leqslant h(0)$.

However, for the punctured unit disk, we have a harmonic - and hence subharmonic - function that helps: $\lambda(z) := \log \lvert z\rvert$ is harmonic in $D$, vanishes on the unit circle, and tends to $-\infty$ for $z\to 0$. Further, $\lim\limits_{c\to 0} c\cdot \lambda(z) = 0$ for all $z\in D$.

Judicious use of $c\cdot \lambda$ makes your idea work out.

Comment: I understand that given a subsolution on the whole disk, $u+c \log|z|$ is a subsolution of the punctured disk, so the perron solution in the whole disk is at most the perron solution in the punctured disk. But how do we prove the other direction, that every punctured subsolution is a minorant of some whole subsolution?

Comment: For $c > 0$, we have $h_p + c\lambda \in \mathcal{F}_h$, so $$\tilde{h}(z)  \geqslant \sup_{c > 0} \bigl(h_p(z) + c\lambda(z)\bigr) = h_p(z).$$ On the other hand, for $c < 0$ and $u \in \mathcal{F}_h$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $u(z) \leqslant h_p(z) + c\lambda(z)$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ and $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \delta$. Since $u$ is subharmonic on $D$, it follows that $u(z) \leqslant h_p(z) + c\lambda(z)$ for all $z \in D$, so $\tilde{h}(z) \leqslant h_p(z) + c\lambda(z)$ for all $c < 0$, whence $\tilde{h}(z) \leqslant h_p(z)$.