# Perron solution on the punctured unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

[Perron Solution is Precisely Poisson Integral on Punctured Disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681469/perron-solution-is-precisely-poisson-integral-on-punctured-disk)

I got the same problem described in this question while I am solving the problem. I read the accepted answer too But I do not really understand how $\lambda(z)$ relates to $h_p$ here. I guess we wanted $h_p(0) \leqslant h(0)$. But how does it follow from this answer? Can anybody please elaborate the answer?